# Determine whether a set is a subgroup of a permutation group

Tags: abstract-algebra, solution-verification

Let $A$ be a set, $B\subseteq A$, and $b\in B$.

$C = \{\sigma\in S_A \mid \sigma[B]\subseteq B\}$, where $\sigma[B]$ is the image of B, and $S_A$ is the permutation group of A.

Is the following reasoning rigorous enough to verify that $C$ is closed under the operation of $S_A$?

Let $c_1, c_2\in C$.

Then, $c_1c_2 \in C$ because $(c_1c_2)(b) = c_1(c_2(b)) \in B$.

Because $c_2\in C$, $\{ c_2(x) \mid x\in B \} \subseteq B$, so $c_2(b)\in B$. Likewise, $c_1(c_2(b)) \in B$.

Because this applies for all $b \in B$, $C$ is closed under the operation of $S_A$.

Comment: This is correct. Think carefully about whether the set is closed under inverses though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You also need to check if the subgroup contains the identity (that's easy) and that it is closed under inverses - but that is actually false when $B$ and $A \setminus B$ are infinite. Consider $A = \mathbb{N}$, $B = 2\mathbb{N}$ (the even numbers). The injective map $B \to B$, $b \mapsto 2b$ can be extended to a bijection $f : A \to A$ (since $A \setminus B$ and $A \setminus 2B$ are both countably infinite), but since $f(B)$ is a proper subset of $B$, $f^{-1}(B) \not\subseteq B$.

What *is* correct: $\{f \in S_A : f(B)=B\}$ is a subgroup of $S_A$. See [Finding subgroups of $S_n$ using any subset of $S = \{1, ..., n \}$.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3642875)

Comment: Interesting, I thought about exactly the same example. I guess it's a natural one, as $\mathbb{N}$ is the simplest example of an infinite set.

Comment: Why do you comment then that the proof is correct? (And also write an answer in a comment...)

Comment: Because OP asked a specific question, was his proof for closure rigorous enough. I also wrote about inverses there.

Comment: Ah ok I read "the operation" wrongly as "the operations".